How to configure Dapper type handlers on per-instance basis?
I was using SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler to make Dapper to work around certain column types, but then I had to utilize two DB connections at the same time, and the databases are different, so the column types are different too. The type handlers are necessary for one DB, but I don't want them for the other.
Is there a way making different Dapper instances to use different set of type handlers?

I haven't tried this, but you could reset the typehandlers and add the one for your purpose. Something like:
SqlMapper.ResetTypeHandlers();
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(myPurpose1TypeHandler);
connection1.QueryAsync(...);
...
SqlMapper.ResetTypeHandlers();
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(myPurpose2TypeHandler);
connection2.QueryAsync(...);

I have no idea how it would perform.

Not in my scenario, but thanks anyways. For now I managed to make the type handlers to work around both databases, since I have information about types both from runtime and the DBs, so just a few switch expressions.
